# .NET based UI Toolkit for drag and dropping simple shapes?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I'm want to build a app that allows people to drag and drop simple shapes onto it, and allow them to rotate, resize them.

Are there any tool kits that offer this functionality for .NET--I'd like to avoid writing this from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I've found to such things is this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx?msg=3168123

Having done something like this previously, I think its much simpler than it looks. Its just the adorner bit thats a little tricky. But the code project article explains it quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow this it'll show you how to drag and drop between Itemscontrols in WPF.

[Bea Stolnitz drag and drop tutorial in WPF](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/index.php?s=drag+drop)

For a GUI application you can then modify this to drag shapes from your items control to a canvas with the left click and with the right click you can then rotate item.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo program with source code: [Crafting a C# Forms Editor from scratch](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SharpFormEditorDemo.aspx) It doesn't have all the features you need but can be a good start.